# Profiling subprocess Popen calls in Python

Tags: python, profiling, subprocess, popen

I have a programm that calls several external scripts by using popen from subprocess. Now I want to profile this programm. While I can easily profile the python code with cProfile I get no information on how long the different external scripts run.

I want to avoid messuring every single popen call with a timer.

Thank you!

Comment: You could wrap the call to Popen in a separate function and write the timing code only once

Comment: The problem is that there are a lot of different Popen calls. Of course I could manually time the different calls and sum them all up by category. But I'd rater have some tool or generic approach or confirmation that such a tool or approach does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Simeon said, you just need to write the timing code once. A way to do it would be to [decorate](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) the popen function.